Математические вычисления на python
Есть задание для решения лабораторной работы по программированию:
Написать программу вычисления значения выражения при заданных
исходных данных. Сравнить полученное значение с указанным правильным
результатом.

мой код:
s = - math.sqrt(math.fabs(x) * math.log(y)) * x + 
     (math.sqrt(math.fabs(x) * math.log(y) + y) / 2) + 
     (z ** 2 / 1 + z ** 2)


Какая связь формулы и этого кода? В чём вообще вопрос?

Добрый день, необходимо вычислить данное выражение с помощью кода, но как я не кручу у меня не получается. Если считать квадратный корень в отрицательной степени выдаёт ошибку. Я сократил выражение с помощью программы photomath и попробовал записать в сокращенном виде но ответ не сходится, я не понимаю что я делаю не так

Да, что-то код вообще про какую-то другую формулу. Причём, сложностей то никаких тут нет. Просто идти изнутри скобок наружу. Сначала делаете то, что в скобках. Причём, большинство операций тупо переводится в вызовы math.функция. Потом ставите скобки и снаружи скобок делаете тоже самое. Чтобы в коде были те же скобки, что и в формуле. Можно и не изнутри скобок идти, а по порядку просто, это дело вкуса. Главное скобки соблюсти.

А, про оптимизацию с выносом степени из логарифма до меня не сразу дошло. Но в целом - весь вопрос в том, чтобы скобки правильно воспроизвести, у вас какая-то ерунда со вторыми скобками из формулы при переносе в код получилась.

Я бы на вашем месте не мучился с преобразованиями (неверными), а просто написал так, как в исходной формуле (впрочем, логарифм от степени я все же оставил, но написал корректно, а не как у вас...):
from math import * 

x = -15.246
y = 4.642e-2
z = 21

t = sin(atan(z))
s = - sqrt(fabs(x)) * log(y) * (x - y/2) + t*t

print(s)


Да в принципе и t выносить не за чем, sin(atan(z))**2 смотрится нормально же.

Спасибо вам и комментатору выше @CrazyElf, все получилось и я понял в чем была моя ошибка!

s = round(- sqrt(fabs(x)) * log(y) * (x - y/2) + sin(atan(z)) * sin(atan(z)), 3) вот так в итоге получилось, а подскажите как вы это перевели y = 4.642e-2 ?

Что значит "перевел"? у вас это значение записано в условии...

Это зачем вы round добавили?

y = 4.642 * (10 ** -2) просто я таким образом использовал, я и не знал что таим образом можно записывать в переменную

round добавил что бы соответствовало ответу в условиях задания.

Вам не нужно округлять. Наоборот вам нужно вычесть из того, что получится, то, что вам дали для сравнения, и сказать - разница получилась небольшая, в 4-м знаке после запятой (ну или как там получится)

Понял, спасибо!

А про запись чисел с e почитайте тут: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C особенно абзац "Экспоненциальная запись числа в компьютере"

Ну хотя можно наверное и через округление тоже. Но через вычитание информации больше будет о точности вычисления.
